# How to remove file log with file name

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, scripting

Assume, I have log files with this name format.

```
NameLog.log.2014-09-27
NameLog.log.2014-09-28
NameLog.log.2014-09-29
NameLog.log.2014-09-30
NameLog.log.2014-10-01
NameLog.log.2014-10-02
NameLog.log.2014-10-03
NameLog.log.2014-10-04
```

I want to delete the log file only

```
NameLog.log.2014-09-27
NameLog.log.2014-09-28
NameLog.log.2014-09-29
NameLog.log.2014-09-30
```

Actually I want the file log keep just 30 files.
How to solve this with a `bash` script?

Comment: Why are you trying to [reinvent the wheel](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html)?

Comment: I don't how to solve with format file name.
But I was think with easy linux commands.

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way to accomplish what you want, is to delete all files in the directory that are older than 30 days. You can use this `find` command:

```
find /path/to/log/ -maxdepth 1 -name "NameLog.log*" -mtime +30 -delete
```

**Explanation:** (see: [explainshell](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find%20%2Fpath%2Fto%2Flog%2F%20-maxdepth%201%20-name%20%22NameLog.log*%22%20-mtime%20%2B30%20-delete))

- `-maxdepth 1`: don't go deeper into the folder structure
- `-name "NameLog.log*"`: applies only on log file with that name
- `-mtime +30`: that have a modification time older than 30 days
- `-delete`: delete them

Comment: +1 for adressing the root of the problem. And +1 for making me discover explainshell ^^

Comment: @OlivierDulac so, +2 in total? =)

Comment: I wish I could ^^ (and I didn't click twice ;) )